# RegEx - How to change two double quotes to one double quote?

Tags: regex, bash

I have a bunch of strings:

```
pipe 1/4"" square
3" bar
3/16"" spanner
nozzle 2"" 
1/2"" tube pipe with 6"" cut out
```

I want to replace the 2 double quotation marks from a string with Regex. I've been trying on some code with the aid of some [references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx) but cannot seem to do it right.

Ideally once RegEx'ed I would like to pass it into a `$var` that I can call further on in my script.

Q: What is the Regex that will do this with Bash?

Comment: `sed 's/""/"/g' file` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed 's/""/"/g' input_file > output_file
```

Or, process the input line by line and use parameter expansion:

```
while read -r line ; do
    line=${line//\"\"/\"}
    echo "$line"
done < input_file
```

`/g` in sed and `//` in the expansion serve the same purpose:  they'll apply the substitution on all occurrences on a line.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Bash parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
echo "${var//\"\"/\"}"
```

sample output:

```
pipe 1/4" square
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gawk:

```
echo $varName | gawk '{ gsub(/""/,"\"") } 1'
```

or the sed command:

```
echo $varName | sed 's/""/"/g'
```

I assumed your variable is named varName.

Instead if you need to to this for a file:

```
gawk '{ gsub(/""/,""") } 1'  fileName
```

or

```
 sed 's/""/"/g' fileName
```